# jQuery variable not being updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using HTML5 file API to get the width of an image.

Its working, and the console.log is outputting the correct amount.

I need to save the value to the variable `fileWidth` so I can access it outside the function. I have created an empty variable outside the function, and expected it to be updated with the alue inside the function, but whatever I try fails.

Here is my code:

```
var fileWidth;
var reader = new FileReader;
reader.onload = function() {
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function() {
        fileWidth = img.width;
        console.log(fileWidth);
    };
    img.src = reader.result;
};

reader.readAsDataURL($('#submission-file')[0].files[0]);
```

Can anyone see why the variable isn't being updated?

Edited Code:

```
var fileWidth;
var reader = new FileReader;
reader.onload = function() {
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = reader.result;
};
reader.onloadend = function() {
    fileWidth = img.width;  
};

reader.readAsDataURL($('#submission-file')[0].files[0]);

console.log(fileWidth);
```

Comment: Probably an async function.

Comment: Dont you need the `onloadend` event for reader instead ?

Comment: @ccdavies, take a look at the [File APIs](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader "File API - FileReader").

Comment: @SaintGerbil Thanks, but I tried this already.

Comment: @chrismborland Again, thanks, but thats where I came from. I am obviously doing something wrong here, but can't see it myself...

Comment: @ccdavies, Where/how are you trying to access `fileWidth`?

Comment: This is working for me I've put a fiddle together.
http://jsfiddle.net/SaintGerbil/m8sf3/

I'm assuming you have the jquery onready and are selecting an image.

Comment: @chrismborland I am trying to access it just below the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `fileWidth` in an asynchronous callback, this method isn't guaranteed to have executed prior to your accessing the variable.

#### Hint

Try putting an alert in your callback and an alert right before you access the variable.  See which alert is presented first.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, but how do I ensure it has run before hand?

Comment: What @SaintGerbil said or access `fileWidth` once you know your onload method has been called (i.e. create an `onloadend` event and access it there).

Comment: @chrismborland Thank you for this answer, but I can't figure this out. 

I have changed my code in the question to show what I thought I needed to do, but I am obviously way off. Could you possibily explain how I can use the onloadend in this instance?

Comment: @ccdavies, I just noticed that you have nested asynchronous callbacks `img.onload` inside of `reader.onload`, which means you're not even guaranteed to have your `fileWidth` when `reader.onload` has finished its execution.  Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrismborland/UEa3t/ "jsFiddle") and notice the order of execution (alerts).